# OSError: [WinError 123] (file name error) but project previously worked

Tags: python, django

I have written an authentification application with Django and it used to work
now, when I try to use it in another project, I have an error:
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect ''

error seems to deal with a pathlib.py file I did not change:
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)

I try to go back with my original code that was working by cloning my project on gitlab but I have the same error

what happen?